# Remove quotes from a json in a key value iteration

Tags: python, pymongo

I want to add some users based on a dictionary with pymongo, but pymongo fails to validate role and db because I'm getting the value with quotes:

```
USERS = {
      "topology": "{'role': 'readWrite', 'db': 'ui'},{'role': 'readWrite', 'db': 'linkage'},{'role': 'readWrite', 'db': 'metrics'},{'role': 'readWrite', 'db': 'migrations'},{'role': 'readWrite', 'db': 'state'},{'role': 'readWrite', 'db': 'storm'}",
      "uiWriter": "{'role': 'readWrite', 'db': 'ui'}",
      "reports": "{'role': 'readWrite', 'db': 'ui'}",
      "dr": "{'role': 'clusterAdmin', 'db': 'admin'}",
      "eventapi": "{'role': 'readWrite', 'db': 'dedup'},{'role': 'readWrite', 'db': 'lookup'}"
    }
for k,v in USERS.items():
    client = MongoClient(mongos,
                        username=mongo_admin_user,
                        password=mongo_admin_pass,
                        authSource='admin')
    client.admin.add_user(k, mongo_key[k], roles=[v])
    print({v})
```

If I print the value with brackets print({v}) the quotes are visible. I tried with replace but doesn't work. I also tried changing the quotes double with single without luck. If I put the value roles=[{'role': 'readWrite', 'db': 'ui'}] overwritten, it works and validates.
Error:

```
"errorMessage": "No role named {'role': 'readWrite', 'db':
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
for k,v in json.loads(json.dumps(USERS)).items():
    print k, v
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the values into actual objects. You can do this with

```
import json
USERS = {k: json.loads(v) for k, v in USERS}
```

Comment: json.loads expects the property strings to be in double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You need a array of dicts as value for roles. So may be try this.

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> roles_value = []
>>> for k,v in USERS.items():
...     roles_value = list(literal_eval(v))
```

P.S. add_user function is deprecated..

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex. (with import json)
Example:
r"[a-zA-Z]+

Comment: As the strings are json, they should be parsed with the json module.

Answer (score 0):

Your string does not have "" or '' around it, rather it is of type string which is obviously expressed with quotes. So regex, replace, etc. won't help evaluate as an expression instead of a string.

I am pretty sure `eval()` or `ast.literal_eval()` should work for your case, with the second one being preferred.

Note that many people dissuade the use of `eval()`.

Comment: As the strings are json, they should be parsed with the json module.

Comment: Yes that is certainly a better solution, even though theoretically eval() and equiv. should work in this situation, no? But yes better to not use it.